# SQL: select only the most recent records from a table, for each member of a set

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, query-performance

I have tables of ads and daily ad performance reports. Each ad automatically generates a report each day. The reports have that day's stats, and a cumulative total of ad views.

```
-------   ----------------------------
| Ads |   | DailyAdPerformanceReport |
-------   ----------------------------
| id  |-->| ad_id (foreign key)      |
-------   | id                       |
          | ...                      |
          | date                     |
          | cumulative_total         |
          ----------------------------
```

I want to get the total number of ad views for sets of ads, by selecting the last report for each ad in the set, and summing the cumulative total views in each report.

Currently I'm doing this by getting a set of ad ids, and running this query for each one to get its last ad report:

```sql
SELECT  "daily_ad_performance_reports"."cumulative_total" 
FROM "daily_ad_performance_reports" 
WHERE "daily_ad_performance_reports"."ad_id" = 1
ORDER BY "daily_ad_performance_reports"."date" DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

I add all of the cumulative totals together to get the result. It works, but running queries for every report is slow - O(n) rather than O(1)

How can I select the last dated records for each of the ads in a single query? Ideally such a query would return a table like this:

```
ad_id | date      | cumulative_total
-------------------------------------
1     | 1/6/2014  | 100
2     | 28/5/2014 | 200
3     | 18/2/2014 | 300
```

Given that, I could easily sum the cumulative total column.

Comment: Sounds like a rownumber group by ad_id order by date but not sure what the question is.

Comment: Syntax error in you query.

Comment: (1) Your query is not correct in any database.  Please fix the query.  (2) Please tag your question with the database you are using.  (3) Sample data that produces the desired results would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm actually using Rails and wrote the query I thought it would produce. Fixed to show the actual query

Comment: @GordonLinoff 1 done 2 seems fine as a generic sql question 3 that's the last part of the question - what's not clear about it?